# Difficulty getting controls in a SurfaceScrollViewer control to gain focus

Tags: wpf, focus, scrollviewer, tablet, pixelsense

This is a bit of a weird one, so I was hoping maybe someone else has come across this as well, and maybe knows how to solve it.

I'm working on a WPF application that will ultimately be run on windows tablet PCs. Because it's a touch screen device, I've used the SurfaceScrollViewer control when showing lists of items to scroll through, and it works really nicely.

I've found that if I show a TextBox control in a SurfaceScrollViewer, you can't edit the textbox unless you tap it repeatedly about five or six times really fast - only then do they gain focus.

If I use a ScrollViewer instead, it works fine. It also works fine when running it on the desktop - this is only a problem on the tablet PC.

Any ideas?

To summarise, this is the main structure: SurfaceScrollViewer / StackPanel / ItemsControl

Even if I just have a single TextBox control as the DataTemplate of the ItemsControl, it still suffers from the same problem.

Oh - and this happens with buttons as well. It's not restricted to the TextBox control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox and Button don't know how to handle Touch events like the Surface* controls do.  When you touch the TextBox, first a touch event gets sent.  The TextBox ignores it so then it goes to the SurfaceScrollViewer.  SSV says "yeah ok, I can do something with this" so it handles the event & captures the input.  TextBox gets no further events related to that touch.

So... the trick is to either handle to TouchDown event on your TextBox... or better yet, just use the SurfaceTextBox control which will do that for you (and other stuff to help with touch).  The same goes for Button/SurfaceButton and many other standard controls.  As a general rule, use the Surface versions of controls whenever they exist.

Comment: That's brilliant - thank you! This does indeed work. Now I just need to apply the correct styles and I should be good to go. Very helpful explanation of why this happens - thanks!